# How can I change the PHP version used by phpmyadmin?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, version

I have phpmyadmin installed on my ubuntu server, that runs several versions of PHP depending on the website used.
The default version is 7.4, but phpmyadmin use 7.2 for unknown reason.
Simple question : where do I change that ?
Cannot find it in any forum or documentation...

I tried to put in phpmyadmin/apache.conf what I use in my virtual hosts sites :

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler "proxy:unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/"
</FilesMatch>
```

but it doesn't work and I still have 7.2

Thanks a lot !

Comment: If you are using Apache, please look at virtual host config file.

Comment: I did it, but my phpmyadmin page is not a virtual host, and I don't know the command to put in phpmyadmin/apache.conf file to redirect all *.php files to 7.4
In my sites conf files I use     
<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler "proxy:unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/"
</FilesMatch>
but it doesn't work in the phpmyadmin/apache.conf file

Answer (score 5):

Solution found !
As my Phpmyadmin installation doesn't use the virtual host file system, the file to modify is /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf

I put a code, but outside the Directory tags, and you have to put it inside to make it work :

```
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin>
    <FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler "proxy:unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/"
    </FilesMatch>
</Directory>
```

And then, restart Apache change the PHP version of phpmyadmin page.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I do it:

Go to phpMyAdmin config

```
cd /etc/apache2/sites-available
```

Open config file

```
sudo nano phpmyadmin.conf
```

Put the following line inside the  tags to serve 7.4:

```
include /etc/apache2/conf-available/php7.4-fpm.conf
```

Restart apache:

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Note that my setup is mostly from [this tutorial](https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/php-multiple-versions-ubuntu).

Answer (score 0):

Add the below code inside  /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf

```
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin>
    <FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler "proxy:unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/"
    </FilesMatch>
</Directory>
```

After that restart Apache

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```